# Open file handles

Tags: files, kernel, sysctl

As I spawn several processes in a loop, I hit the maximum number of open files handles and the for loop breaks.

When I count the open file handles using `lsof` I get:

```
$ lsof | wc -l
1464377
```

However checking `fs.file-nr` returns:

```
$ sysctl fs.file-nr
fs.file-nr = 35328      0       6553201
```

I expected the first number to be 1464377.

I have a couple of questions:

1. What's the difference between the output of lsof (1464377) and
   file-nr (35328).
2. The maximum seems to be 6553201, which looks rather arbitrary.
   What's the maximum value for this number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per `man lsof`

> An  open  file  may  be  a  regular file, a directory, a block special file, a character special file, an executing text reference, a library, a
>          stream or a network file (Internet socket, NFS file or UNIX domain socket.)  A specific file or all the files in a file system may  be  selected
>          by path.

So number of line in `lsof` is likely much more than actual file descriptor.

See this reated question : https://serverfault.com/questions/485262/number-of-file-descriptors-different-between-proc-sys-fs-file-nr-and-proc-pi

Answer (score 0):

@Archemar is right. I'm late with answer. I check it (exclude character special file, network file, dirs ...):

```
$ lsof /|grep -v DIR|wc -l 
1191

$ sysctl fs.file-nr
fs.file-nr = 1280   0   98018
```

There are `1191` opened files and `1280` allocated handles. Values are very nearly.

[Kernel documentation about fs partition on sysctl](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt?h=v4.15.10)

Comment: True, I get closer values but they are still off by a factor of 3. grepped lsof giving me 11410 and file-nr giving me 32640.